# I can't use local data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get the name and surname from the object but I cannot

```
function ToDoScreen({ isLogin }: any) {
  const name: any = localStorage.getItem("inputs");
  console.log(name);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{name.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ToDoScreen;
```

[image]

Comment: check `typeof(name)`. It might be a string instead of Js Object in your case.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please supply all error messages as text, not as a picture of text. Search engines and people with visual impairments cannot read the image.

Comment: `localStorage.getItem` will always return a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local storage can only store *strings* therefore `name` is a string (of JSON as it happens).

If you want to treat it as an object, you need to pass it through `JSON.parse`.

---

Note that this error would have been caught if you'd specified a type for `name` instead of using `:any`. That's the point of using types in TypeScript!

---

You may wish to use the [`useLocalStorage` hook](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) instead of accessing storage directly.

Answer (score 0):

I seems like you are getting the data, you just need to parse it as Json to use it. Try this below and see if it works better for you.

```
function ToDoScreen({ isLogin }: any) {
  const data = localStorage.getItem("inputs");
  var dataJson = JSON.parse(data)
  console.log(dataJson.name);
  console.log(dataJson.lastname);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{dataJson.name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```